# Read file around 400 MB in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to read a file over 500MB (to process something) in google app engine. I know that the resource file should not be over 32 mb, so I tried using Google Cloud Storage to read file usign GCS API.

If reading a file from local server, processing time is less than a second. However, using GCS API, processing time is around 10 seconds.

(I've used cloudstorage.open() function, but seems this is reading from remote location not local... sadly).

So is there other solution to this? Otherwise, I'll have to build another API server to process this.

Comment: What do you need to do with the file? If you need to do a long running task, you should look into using task queues. If you need to read more than 32 megabytes, you should break your read into multiple requests.

Comment: Im using ip2location BIN file to lookup metadata depending on ip address...

Comment: Loading a 400 megabyte file in response to every request in order to determine their location is a huge amount of extra work. You might find it much cheaper and faster to load the IP table into, say, Cloud SQL, then query that instead.

Comment: it should be reading a file (io) from local, not req/res from remote... that's why using cloudstorage is not an option, in my case....

Comment: Not sure whether using Blobstore will solve my problem. any one?